# JDMenu JQuery navigation plugin IE9 bug - plugin abandoned by author

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Hey guys, i'm looking for some help on with the JDMenu plugin for Jquery and it's implementation in IE9. The drop-down action of the navigation fails in IE9. I don't know any details about the operational aspects of this plugin but you can find the source code here: http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/

I've already tried to contact Jonathan Sharp through web form on his company site (outwestmedia.com) with no response. I will leave the 404 page on the site containing the navigation menu set to IE9 mode (all other pages are forced back to IE8 with the "X-UA" tag to keep the navi functioning until i find a solution) for you to see the failure in action.

Sample : http://www.wiki-pet.com/error-pages/404.php

I like the action on this menu, but i'm looking into an all CSS alternative to avoid all the extra bloated plugin files required to run this navigation and the inherent IE9+ compliance issues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what fixed it for me:

1. jQuery 1.6.x
2. Include [bgiframe 2.1.2](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe)

***Note:** You might also need an update to jQueryUI. I am using version 1.8.5 (which is NOT the most recent), and everything seems to be working fine.*

Comment: I haven't upgraded to JQuery 1.6 yet on the site but the upgrade to BGIframe 2.1.2 worked perfectly. Sorry for the double post here - i solution checked the wrong comment first, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution but to say that I have a site which I developed in MVC2 and jdmenu and jquery 1.4.... It exhibits the problem described above.

I also have a new site that I just started developing in MVC3 jdmenu and jquery 1.6.... It does NOT exhibit these symptoms. I haven't taken the time yet to delve into it, but my first guess is that jquery 1.6 in my older site might fix it.

More later.....

Comment: Fantastic diligence Randy! The only thing needed to correct this bug is JQuery BGIframe 2.1.2 (which i didn't know was out yet, lol) Solution works 100% in IE9. Thanks!